# Issue with .NET Framework on Navision 2009R2

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, add-in, navision, dynamics-nav

i'm creating a ControlAddIn for Navision 2009R2 in c# with Visual Studio 2010.
There I have to use the .NET 3.5 Framework because Navision can't use higher versions of the .NET framwork.

The problem is that I have a dll which is based on .NET Framework 4.5.
If i reference it i become over 50 warnings and can't use the dll.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: You have to draw the obvious conclusion from "can't use higher versions".  That means that you can't use it.

Comment: But it can't. There are references to the wrong version of the .Net framework (and the CLR is even the wrong version). You have three choices. Write your own version of the dll, find an old version of the dll that is written for .Net 3.5 (2.0 CLR) or upgrade to NAV 2013 (supports .Net 4.5 (4.0 CLR)).

Answer (score 0):

If you created the dll yourself.
Open your project in visual studio,
click on properties of your project.

In the application tab, set your framework to 3.5, and build your project.

You should be able to use the dll now.